# Angular shows no text on the html page

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I've started learning Angular for my internship. According to its conditions I have to develop a client-server application, with Angular as frontend framework and Spring as backend solution. And in the project I have an `app.component`

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string;

  constructor(){
    this.title = 'My Task Project';
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card bg-dark my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title text-center text-white py-3">{{title}}</h2>
          <ul class="text-center list-inline py-3">
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a routerLink="/people/getAgeByName" class="btn btn-info">Get age by name</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a routerLink="/statistics/getOldest" class="btn btn-info">Get oldest person's name</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This html is injected in the main html page.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Todo</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

And on the resulting page in the browser I see no text at all! It just is not shown! Why this could happen?

Example of the shown page

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors on the console?

Comment: I bet the console is showing some errors, could you check them?

Comment: NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!

Comment: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/src/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: Try adding this to you AppModule imports `RouterModule.forRoot([]),` also make sure you pass relevant routes to `forRoot` once you have some routes in your application

Comment: Manish, adding RouterModule.forRoot([]) helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of our fellow collegues answered, adding `RouterModule.forRoot([])` in imports of AppModule helped!